# cURL and click a button in a website

Tags: scripting, curl

what is the simplest script using cURL of clicking a certain button on a website?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your best bet is to use something like Firebug or the Live HTTP Headers plugin (both are for Firefox) to try actually clicking the button and seeing what is going into the resulting request.  Then try to replicate it.

Here's a simple example, though:

a form on a web site:

```
<form action="http://someUrl.com/somePage.html" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="value1"> <br />
    <input type="text" name="value2"> <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Typing "Some value number one" in the first box, typing "Some value number two" in the second box, and clicking the submit button would generate a request that looks something like

```
POST /somePage.html HTTP/1.1
Host: someUrl.com

...//various other POST headers here

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 57
value1=Some+value+number+one&value2=Some+value+number+two
```

which would translate into a cUrl command like

```
curl -d "value1=Some%20value%20number%20one&value2=Some%20value%20number%20two" http://someUrl.com/somePage.html
```

Answer (score 1):

cURL doesn't parse a DOM itself.  But clicking the button probably just submits a form, which curl can do.  But you need to figure it out the details (the exact fields, and any cookies) first.