# Running a curl command on the click of submit button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, curl

I have a form which accepts input from the user and once the user clicks submit, I want to pick up the submitted info and through a curl command post that data to a URL. I am new to web development and hence struggling with accomplishing this.

I tried doing it through php, but as I understand php is a server side thing.
Can someone help me with writing a possible Javascript or JQuery that would help me accomplish this.

The form looks something like as follows -

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="Ques" value="Opt1" checked>1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Ques" value="Opt2">2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Ques" value="Opt3">3<br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The PHP code that is working looks something like this

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.URL.com/abc');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"abc\": {\"subject\": \"My printer was never on fire!\", \"comment\": { \"body\": \"The smoke is very very colorful.\" }}}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'USERNAME' . ':' . 'API_TOKEN');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Possibly this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366549/curl-and-click-a-button-in-a-website

Comment: Could you make an AJAX request directly from the browser to this URL instead (assuming it supports CORS)? AJAX is the way you make HTTP requests from a browser (apart from clicking on links or submitting forms of course) whereas cURL is a way to make HTTP requests from other environments such as your PHP code.

Comment: I can. But, I have nil experience in AJAX and hence was looking for some help in transforming the cURL to AJAX.

Comment: Well the first thing to do is study an Ajax tutorial /. documentation so you understand the basics, and then you'll hopefully see which options / settings in Ajax syntax correspond to which cURL options - they are all just ways of setting headers and content of the HTTP request, so there should be an equivalent in each case. For the AJAX side the modern way is to use the JavaScript Fetch API so I suggest you search for that. If you get stuck with your conversion attempt then please paste your JavaScript code here and we can take a look. Thanks

Comment: But before you do any of that, first check whether the remote endpoint accepts CORS requests (I'm assuming that this URL is on a different website and domain to where you're calling from?). And if you don't know what CORS is, again you can search and find lots of info about it. If the remote URL is not on the same domain as your website, and doesn't allow CORS requests, then you will never be able to make an AJAX request to it and there's no point even trying

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and check that.

Comment: @ADyson : the AJAX request thing worked for me. The domain accepts CORS requests. HTML combined with JQuery did the trick for me.